# Detecting support for "application/pdf" in Microsoft Edge

Tags: pdf, windows-10, microsoft-edge

Our site tries to detect support for the `application/pdf` mimetype via a check like this:

```js
function isPdfMimeTypeSupported() {
  if (navigator.mimeTypes != null && navigator.mimeTypes.length > 0)
    for (i = 0; i < navigator.mimeTypes.length; i++) {
      var mtype = navigator.mimeTypes[i];
      if (mtype.type == "application/pdf" && mtype.enabledPlugin)
        return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

This works as expected in Chrome however in Microsoft Edge the mimeTypes collection only has two entries:

- "application/x-shockwave-flash"
- "application/futuresplash"

The check fails and we are incorrectly warning the user that their browser doesn't support PDF.

If there a way to check for PDF support in JavaScript that works in Edge?

Comment: This could indicate that Edge does not natively support PDFs, however [this comment](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-confirms-its-new-edge-browser-wont-support-its-silverlight-player#comment-1885465) from a Microsoft developer says PDF's are natively supported. I wonder if this is a bug (feature)?

Comment: I wonder if you can query `navigator.plugins` and look for the specific Edge PDF renderer?

Comment: I should note that Edge does, in fact, support PDFs natively. If I use the F12 tools to bypass this check and just let it try, it's able to display the PDF just fine. We're just trying to avoid user agent sniffing and do proper feature detection... which is where we're hitting a roadblock. Not sure how to check for this feature in Edge!

Comment: Also, we checked navigator.plugins. It only has 1 entry which is for "Shockwave Flash". So that won't work, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Important: The following answer is relevant only for a specific period of time*

Microsoft Edge, as suggested above, ships with native PDF viewing support built-in. I don't *believe* there are any versions of Edge that lack this functionality, but if there are, they would be very rare.

We are currently planning to update `navigator.mimeType` in the near future, which will cause your present approach (as presented above) to begin working. Until that time, I would encourage you to (I feel terrible for suggesting this) sniff the user-agent string.

This issue will be resolved in a future update to Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Great answer. Has the issue been resolved now? (And is there any region-specific aspect to this? E.g., can we expect built-in PDF viewing to work in Edge in the U.S., Europe, Asia, ...?) Thanks in advance. (Edit: I see from your profile you're no longer with MS. Please don't go to any trouble to answer, but if you happen to know...)

Answer (score 1):

Check which version of Windows 10 you are using.

If you are using an N edition, then PDF support is not available out-of-the-box, and you'll need to install the [Windows 10 Media Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231) or [Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?platform=windows&product=10).

For more information see [Windows N editions explained](http://www.cnet.com/uk/news/windows-7-n-the-n-editions-explained/)

Comment: Mark - We're using the USA version of Windows 10. Your link regarding the "N" versions appears to be a UK/Euro specific version. The version we have does indeed support native PDF display, we're just trying to figure out how to detect this feature via JavaScript on the client side.